# Match values between 2 data frame and update using user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dataframe

```
Dataframe1 = IndicatorDF - columns ['Code', 'Name', 'Indicator']

Dataframe2 = IndicatorRSK - columns ['Indicator', 'Code', 'Name']
```

Want to update `Dataframe1` filed: Indicator by mapping with `Dataframe2` where `IndicatorDF['Code'] == IndicatorRSK['Code']` & update `IndicatorRSK['Indicator']` values to `IndicatorDF['Indicator']`

Below script works fine, But I want update for many dataframe. Can we do this using user defined function.

```
mappingD = IndicatorDF[['Code', 'Indicator']].set_index('Code')
mappingD.update(IndicatorRSK.set_index('Code'))
IndicatorDF['Indicator'] = mappingD.values
```

I wrote below function, but not working, please help on the same.

```
IndicatorDF = pd.read_excel(r'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\imf\IMFBOP2017\4_Updation2017Apr\IMFBOP2017.xlsx', sheetname = 'Indicator')
IndicatorDF['Indicator'] = ''

IndicatorRSK = pd.read_csv(r'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\imf\IMFBOP2017\4_Updation2017Apr\Prod_IMFBOP2017\Prod_IMFBOP2017_Indicator.csv', dtype=object)
IndicatorRSK.rename(columns={'Key': 'Indicator'}, inplace=True)

def mapping(resultDF, indexCol, resultCol, mapDF, mapIndex):
    mappingD = resultDF[[indexCol, resultCol]].set_index(indexCol)
    mappingD.update(mapDF.set_index(mapIndex))
    resultDF[resultCol] = mappingD.values
    return

mapping('IndicatorDF', 'Code', 'Indicator', 'IndicatorRSK', 'Code') # passing data frame name and field name

IndicatorDF.to_csv(r'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\imf\IMFBOP2017\4_Updation2017Apr\Prod_IMFBOP2017\mapped.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Apostrophe from dataFrame, as you are passing object. Hope this will work
mapping(IndicatorDF, 'Code', 'Indicator', IndicatorRSK, 'Code')